# Elastic potential energy in spring

Tags: energy, work, potential-energy, spring, elasticity

We generate the formula from $W=Fs$, but why is it when we form the formula the $F$ becomes the average force applied, making the equation

$$W=(1/2)(0+F)x \, ?$$

Answer (score 2):

Because the force applied changes with $x$.

Note that Hookes Law for springs is: $$F = k \Delta x$$

This means that in the $W = F s$ equation, we cannot directly use it because $F$ is not constant throughout the entire $\Delta x$ movement.

Since it varies linearly, we can instead take the **average** force multiplied by the total distance to find the work done, since we are not doing work with the max force the entire time.